# Why is my IDEA reporting this error - "Cannot resolve symbol 'synchronizedList'"

Tags: java, collections, synchronize

```
public static List<Socket>  socketList = new Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

In the code, `Collections.synchronizedList`, prompt me Cannot resolve symbol `synchronizedList`, I don't know what it is. I didn't find this method for `Collections` in the `JDK` documentation either (just because I probably couldn't find it, doesn't mean he didn't).

Maybe it's a problem with my IDEA setup, but I can't find it.

Comment: `new Collections.synchronizedList` remove 'new' keyword, it thinks you are looking for an inner class when you are not

Answer (score 2):

because `synchronizedList` is not a class from `Collections` - it is a method.

Remove the `new` keyword from that statement:

```
public static List<Socket>  socketList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
```

The `new` keyword is used to create a new instance of a class and requires a class, but the compiler is not able to find that class => symbol not found

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `new` statement from Collections.

public static List socketList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());